# Regex in Aggregation not returning documents in right order

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am using the aggregation below to search user by `user_name` and `full_name` fields.

```
[{
      $match: {
        $or: [
          {
            user_name: {
              $regex: q.trim(),
              $options: 'i',
            },
          },
          {
            full_name: {
              $regex: q.trim(),
              $options: 'i',
            },
          },
        ],
        initialized: true,
        _id: {
          $nin: [userId, ...blockedUsers],
        },
      },
    }]
```

The result for the above query with `q='s'` is:

```
[
{
  "_id": "62073c243c74c43befc9249f",
  "user_name": "carolina",
  "full_name": "Caroline Forbes",
  "initialized":true

},
{
  "_id": "62073d0a3c74c43befc924e9",
  "user_name": "stefan",
  "full_name": "Stefan",
  "initialized":true
},
{
  "_id": "62073d0a3c74c43befc924e9",
  "user_name": "steve",
  "full_name": "Steve",
  "initialized":true
}
]
```

As you see the order in which documents are coming is not correct `carolina` should be below `stefan` and `steve`
Working example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/RPL_4mpe1DS

Answer (score -1):

Your code works fine with me.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [
        {
          user_name: {
            $regex: "ste",
            $options: "i"
          }
        },
        {
          full_name: {
            $regex: "ste",
            $options: "i"
          }
        }
      ],
      initialized: true,
      _id: {
        $nin: []
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/w2zKQ8jOFau)

Comment: Sorry my bad try with only 's', I forgot to state that in question.

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/RPL_4mpe1DS see here

Comment: @Bond007  `"Caroline Forbes"`  did have `s` in `Forbes`. So the query return the right thing

Comment: But the question i posted is not about matching but ordering of the documents according to best match `steve` and `stefan` are better match, so why are they not appearing at top and how to fix it?